# Скрестил Formik и ANTD помогите получить данные с формы

Tags: reactjs, redux, formit

Всем привет, традиционно "Я новичок" и всё остальное. ;)
Удалось мне скрестить форму от ant.design и Formik. (Ушло 2 дня, как говорил, я новичок). Выглядит шикарно, и валидация от Formik работает.
И как итог, не могу прочитать данные которые в полях. 
Плиз, гуру помогите понять, что с данными.

```js
// Core
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import { func } from "prop-types";
// Instruments
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { creatorAgent } from '../../bus/forms/shapes';
// Antd
import { Modal, Input, Icon, Form } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
// Styles
// import Styles from '../styles.m.css';

let isValidForm = true;

export default class CreatorAgent extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        _cancelCreateAgent: func.isRequired,
        _createAgent:       func.isRequired,
    };

    formikForm = createRef();

    _submitForm = (data) => {
        if (isValidForm) {
            const { _createAgent } = this.props;

            console.log(` data ->`, data);

            console.log(` this.props ->`, this.props);
            debugger;

            _createAgent();
        } else {
            console.log(`Форма не валидна _submitForm ->`, isValidForm);
        }

    };

    _cancel = () => {
        const { _cancelCreateAgent } = this.props;

        _cancelCreateAgent();
    };

    render () {
        const {
            confirmLoading,
            visible,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <Modal
                cancelText = 'Отмена'
                confirmLoading = { confirmLoading }
                okText = 'Создать'
                onCancel = { this._cancel }
                onOk = { this._submitForm }
                title = 'Создание агента'
                visible = { visible }>

                <Formik
                    initialValues = { creatorAgent.shape }
                    ref = { this.formikForm }
                    render = { (props) => {
                        const {
                            values,
                            initialValues,
                            errors,
                            isValid,
                            handleChange,
                            handleBlur,
                        } = props;

                        isValidForm = isValid;

                        console.log(`Formik props ->`, props);

                        return (
                            <div>
                                <Form>
                                    <FormItem
                                        help = { errors.nameAgent ? errors.nameAgent : "" }
                                        validateStatus = { errors.nameAgent ? 'error' : 'success' }
                                        hasFeedback >
                                        <Input
                                            defaultValue = { initialValues.nameAgent }
                                            name = 'nameAgent'
                                            onBlur = { handleBlur }
                                            onChange = { handleChange }
                                            placeholder = 'Наименование'
                                            prefix = { <Icon style = { { color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" } } type = 'user' /> }
                                            value = { values.nameAgent }
                                            onPressEnter = { this._submitForm }
                                        />
                                    </FormItem>

                                </Form>
                            </div>
                        );
                    } }
                    validationSchema = { creatorAgent.schema }
                    onSubmit = { this._submitForm }
                />
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

Хочу в data получить данные формы, а там не пойми для меня что.
[image: данные в data]

Подскажите, плиз, как при при сабмите получить данные из полей. 
PS: Теоретически можно, при рендере записывать "values.nameAgent" в стейт или в глобальную переменную как в строке:

```js
let isValidForm = true;
```

, и при собмите его читать, но мне кажется должен быть более простой способ.